# gvfs-mount specify username password

Tags: ubuntu

Is there anyway to specify / pass a username password to gvfs-mount so that I can run it from a script without it waiting for the user to specify input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a simple expect script?
Something like this...you will need to change...just an outline

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect --
set timeout -1
spawn gvfs-mount {args}
expect "User"
send "joe\n"
expect "Password:"
send "xxxxx\n"
```

Comment: I don't like doing this, just seems not very robust, but I guess expect is alot better than pipeing echo to it!

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for any future visitors (like myself) I could not get the expect script to work until I added another line "expect eof" to the script - then it worked like a charm!
Thanks for the tip joemooney!

Answer (score 2):

smb urls generally work along these lines:

```
smb://[[domain;]username[:password]@]server[/share[/path]]
```

I haven't tested gvfs-mount will accept the password like this but certainly it works for username and domain.  gvfs-mount can just uses a stored password, if the user has stored one.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa: YMMV.  It works for me, and is consistent with the latest draft ietf document.  SMB URLs have never become a fully blessed standard though.

Comment: How make password with special symbols like `p@ssword`? [Anyone knows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1508382/gio-mount-password-with-special-characters)?

Answer (score 2):

This may be an older post but I didn't get it to work when I needed it recently. Now I have found a solution on the [german Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/gvfs-mount/#Mount-Skript). It works like a charm now.

Have a file with your login data, leave a blank line if you don't need e.g. the Domain (order as gvfs-mount asks for it):

```
username
domain
password
```

Then, in your script, simply call `gvfs-mount smb://server/path < path/to/login/data`, and here you go! I think you could also do it without a file, passing a string like that: `echo 'username\ndomain\npassword' | gvfs-mount smb://server/path`, but it didn't work when I tried. I don't know why, it suddenly didn't ask for a password or something...